# Set minimum height of timeslots in full calendar

Tags: html, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-6

I am using fullcalendar v6.1.8 in timegrid view with vertical resources.

I want to make the timeslots appear as the same size, regardless of the slot duration.

For example, when I switch to a 15m slots, it currently just split the exist slot into 4 segments. I would rather is stretch it out.

Is this possible via css? I haven't been able to find any settings to control this (I found one for the horizontal resource mode called slotMinWidth)

Comment: I think the slot heights are calculated to some extent relative to the overall height of the calendar and the number of slots that are needed. Why do you need/want the slots to be bigger? Won't it just increase the height needed and the amount of scrolling a user has to do to see each day? Surely the slots only need to be big enough to hold the events within them, and otherwise just a fairly small amount of space?

Comment: That said, although you may be able to resort to CSS (each slot is implemented by a simple `<tr>` as far as I can see), you might find that some of the [sizing options](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/sizing) get you closer to your goal. `expandRows` might potentially be useful, for example.